# How can I find co-ordiantes of points inside a circle in 3D space using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I created a circle in MATLAB using following code. 
I need to find the points inside the circle in 3D space

```
    radius = 5;
    theta=linspace(0,2*pi);
    rho=ones(1,100).*radius;

    [x,z]=pol2cart(theta,rho);

    y=center(2)*ones(1,length(x))
    fill3(x,y,z,'yellow')
```

How can I find Cartesian co-ordinates of points inside this circle?

Comment: Do you have a circle or a sphere?

Comment: y is all 0, so it seems it is a circle in a 3D space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I'm understanding well your question. Obviously there are infinite points inside the circle so I guess you want to check whether a point (or a set of points) is inside or not. If you loop through a list of points, those who meet the following criteria are inside (or in the perimeter of the circle):

```
 norm([xi,zi]) <= radius
 yi = 0 (same plane)
```

Was this what you were asking?

Edit: you can do it pretty quickly in matlab without a loop. Lets imagine you have x = [1 2 3] and z = [4 5 6]. To check all combinations you can use `repmat` with x and z' (transverse) to obtain: xr = [ 1 2 3; 1 2 3; 1 2 3] and zr = [ 4 4 4 ; 5 5 5 ; 6 6 6]. So you have 2 matrixes with the coordinates of all possible points. Now you can calculate the norm as: `N = sqrt(xr.^2+zr.^2)`. All `i,j` with `Nij <= radius` are inside your circle (considering all your x and z are <= radius of course)

Comment: we don't need to consider infinite points. just take linspace(min(x),max(x) and linspace(min(z),max(z). Can we find solution?